# NVidia Drivers for a GeForce GTS 450 on Ubuntu 14.04 - Which one works?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

Regarding drivers for GeForce GTS 450 on Ubuntu 14.04 - which one works?

For a while I had my Nvidia setup *perfect*. One day recently it just malfunctioned - I think an update threw it off.

There are quite a few options to set up the Nvidia, and the option most appropriate for my Nvidia 450 is the **legacy or binary driver  304.123 (open source)**, yet that does not seem to work properly.

The one I'm using now is the version version 331.98 (proprietary) and while it seems moderately useful, it does not perform correctly in instances like 3d rendering and gaming.

What is the correct, or at least the best case set up for my environment?

Answer (score 1):

1. 304.123 is provided by Nvidia, and it's not supposed to be Open Source, but proprietary.
2. According to Driver info' provided by Nvidia, your graphics card is supported by 304.123
   [Nvidia references to driver 304.123](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/77034/en-us)
3. Maybe you should contact Nvidia Customer Care support and ask for help there. I recently opened an issue there due to an issue with driver 304.127.